# Cannot load graphlab.sframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, graphlab

I have joined Machine Learning course on coursera. I am facing an issue while executing following command:

```
    sales = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
```

THe error is as follows:

```
IOError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e5b5a1ead746> in <module>()
----> 1 sales = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl')


C:\Users\admin\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab                         
\data_structures\sframe.pyc in __init__(self, data, format, _proxy)
951                     pass
952                 else:
--> 953                     raise ValueError('Unknown input type: ' + format)
954 
955         sframe_size = -1

C:\Users\admin\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\cython\context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
 47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
 48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
 ---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
 50             else:
 51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let      exception propagate

 IOError: Cannot open C:/Users/admin/home_data.gl/dir_archive.ini for read. Cannot open C:/Users/admin/home_data.gl/dir_archive.ini for reading
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked into the cause of the IOError? The last line of what you've pasted might be a clue.

Comment: [From the help page: “3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.”]

Comment: I can manually open that file "dir_archive.ini". Couldyou please tell me what else should I check?

Comment: I am trying to program while watching the videos. This way it helps to understand new things in a better way rather than using the readymade notebook. If in future I face any problem in homework assignment then I will make it a point to consider the points you have mentioned

Comment: And that sounds like a good way to learn. Please compare your work with the “ready made” notebook to see if you have any obvious differences in your code next, though?

Comment: I am facing same issue for the ready made notebook

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal and run:

```
unzip home_data.gl.zip
```

You will see following files in directory **home_data.gl**:

[image]

Now in ipython, run:

```
sales = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
sales
```

which will display the data in tabular format:

[image]